# How to add a Formula value based on Comments at the task level

Tags: formula, activities

I want to create a Formula that takes some of the text values from the field 'Comments' in a Task.

The issue here is that you can only create the field at the Activity Level. When creating the formula at the activity level I'm not able to see the 'Comment' field

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Comments field is `Long Text Area (32000)` and Long Text Area field cannot be used in Formula field.

It is not about Task or Activity, this rule is globally applicable.

You can verify this upon trying to create custom formula field at Account object, referencing `Description`, you will see this same thing as stated above.

The same rule is applicable to `Rich Text Area` field too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Santanu. Do you happen to know a workaround to get the value of the Comments?

Comment: Basically, you need to handle this through apex. Rather than creating formula, writing a logic in trigger which will read value from Comments and update the new field based on logic